# Control 2 steppers and 1 servo a the same time on a motor Hat

Tags: servo, hat

[image: The Motor Hat I have]Basically, I have a raspberry pi 4 with a Motor Hat to control two stepper motors. The whole thing looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIjzI.jpg

Now I want to connect a servo motor, and I know that you can connect some servo motors using a the 40-pin GPIO from the rasberry pi, but can you connect one from the 40-pin GPIO extension from the Motor Hat ?

Edit : I didn't see the dedicated pins for the servo motors on the motor Hat(lower right of the Image), can I control 2 steppers and 1 servo a the same time though ?

Answer (score 0):

A servo typically has three wires.  You provide power via two (+ve and ground) and a control signal via the third.

You need to connect the control signal to a GPIO.

As long as your set up allows you to connect a wire to something electrically connected to the chosen GPIO it will work.  I assume your HAT allows such a connection.

Note that you also need to connect the servo ground wire to a Pi ground as well as the servo power supply ground.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by searching were the ground and power pins were I found that I have dedicated servo pins seperatly from the other pins(I've added a better Image on the edited post where they are visible), now I just need to find out if I can control 2 steppers and 1 servo a the same time.